# Is there a way to change behavior of rich:panelMenu collapse/expand?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=panelMenu&skin=blueSky

The above link has a demo which is similar to what we have on our application, but we would like for the collapse/expand behavior to act a little differently.

We have our menu starting completely expanded, but we basically want the user to have complete control over collapsing and expanding the menus. For example if you open the top one in the demo and then open the second one the first one closes. Is there a way to only collapse and expand onclick? This seems like it should be the default behavior.

So basically here is what I have:

```
<rich:panelMenu>
    <a4j:repeat>
        <rich:panelMenuGroup>
           <a4j:repeat>
               <h:link />
           </a4j:repeat>
        </rich:panelMenuGroup>
     </a4j:repeat>
</rich:panelMenu>
```

I want to be able to open and close each `rich:panelMenuGroup` without it affecting the rest of the other `rich:panelMenuGroup` elements.

Comment: You mean you want to keep multiple panels open until they're explicitly closed by the user?

Comment: @kolossus That is correct.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be possible with top-level `<rich:panelMenu/>`. You can work out such an arrangement with `<rich:panelMenuGroup/>`s though

Comment: @kolossus Could you explain?

Comment: `<rich:panelMenu/>` can contain multiple `<rich:panelMenuGroup/>`s which in turn contain `<rich:panelMenuItem>`. `<rich:panelMenuGroup/>` item supports multiple simultaneously expanded items with the `expandSingle` attribute. The point here is that `<p:panelMenu/>` doesn't carry that behaviour itself, but its child items do. See [the vdl](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_panelMenu.html) for usage examples

Comment: @kolossus I have updated my question. Any thoughts?

Comment: I probably don't understand what your need is. What I recommended was to have multiple `<rich:panelMenuGroup/>` which can be opened and closed at will by the user. This behaviour is supported by default by the `<rich:panelMenuGroup/>` component

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as: `<rich:panelMenu expandSingle="false">`